# PHP/mySQL Export to CSV but ONLY user selected date range data

Tags: php, date, csv, export, range

i'm stumped and could use some much appreciated help figuring this out.

basically, i've got a page that displays data from a mysql database.

i have a simple text link to export all the data to a CSV file that downloads.
that code is...

```
<a href="log_activity-export2CSV.php?id=<?php echo $colname_CoachActivityListData ?>">Export All</a>
```

...this works just fine.

note: everything is generated based on the user that's logged in - thus the need for the ID.

here is the content/code of the PHP file that exports the above to CSV...

```
<?php 
mysql_select_db($database_vandyConnect, $vandyConnect);

$queryString = "SELECT Created, Last_Updated, coach_name, Start_Date, End_Date, And_Many_More_Columns FROM Activity_Log WHERE User_id = ". $_GET['id'];

$result = mysql_query($queryString, $vandyConnect);

// $result = $db_con->query('SELECT * FROM `Activity_Log`');
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');

$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

$headers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
    $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
}

// $today = date("F_j,_Y,_g:ia");
$today = date("Ymd_g-ia");

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ADEC_Activty_export-'.($today).'.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        fputcsv($fp, $row, ",");
    }
    die;
}
?>
```

...note: i stripped out all the php code from above this that Dreamweaver inserted for me that connects it to the database and user permissions etc.

**SO NOW**, i'm trying to figure out how to add a way for the user to download a CSV file of this data but *ONLY* between certain date ranges that the user picks out.

to begin, i chose to use the JQuery DatePicker that i've used elsewhere in the site, but this time to use its DateRange option...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //to pick date range
$(function() {
    $( "#from_start" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "-2m",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to_end" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#to_end" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "-1m",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from_start" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

...note: this part works fine too.
then i made the html form for the user to select their date range...

```
<form method="POST" action="log_activity-export2CSV.php?id=<?php echo $colname_CoachActivityListData ?>">
    Select a date range from <input type="text" id="from_start" name="from_start" value="" /> to <input type="text" id="to_end" name="to_end" value="" />
    <input name="export" type="submit" value="Export CSV" />
</form>
```

...i gave the "action" the same as the above "export all link",
and here's the kicker/crux of this whole question -
i can't figure out how to push the selected values of the form to the CSV export, so that what downloads is only between the selected date range.

if anybody can guide me, i'd appreciate it.
also note: tho this is a lot of code, i am a total noob with php, so please be gentle ;-)
THANKS,
-jason.

Comment: I don't know the format of your date values, but assuming, that it has the same format as the dates saved in your db you should edit your query to something like ....WHERE User_id = ". $_GET['id'] AND Start_Date >= $_GET['from_start'] and End_Date <= $_GET['to_end']

Comment: hi Felix, THANK YOU for your reply!!!  i actually did try that and it didn't work. so i tried it again by copy/paste your code, and, it still doesn't work. it still just exports the whole thing, not just the selected date range. and, i did make sure my date format is the same (dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',) in the date picker as it is in the date picker for the original submission to the db. any other thoughts?

Comment: FYI: here's another thought i just had... my "Start_Date" and "End_Date" db columns are TEXT types, not "datetime" type. would that have anything to do with this? i chose to use text instead of datetime because it seemed easier at the time, and i wanted to use the jquery datepicker.

Comment: Yes, you should try changing it to datetime.

Comment: doesn't the DATETIME type insert the current date/time of the record submission or will it take the numbers the user inserts into it instead?
this is where the user selects a date range for their activity - not the date of their form submission.
i use the jquery datepicker to make sure the date is formatted consistently.
does that make sense?

Comment: It only inserts the current time if you set the default to "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"